# Import pdf figure to Powerpoint in vector format

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, vector-graphics, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have couple of data plots exported from IBM SPSS in pdf format. They look great. But if I export them in jpeg from SPSS or Adobe Acrobat Pro, some critical elements go missing. Is there a way to export the visualization in a vector format and retain its quality while importing it in MS powerpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to WMF (Windows Meta File) and then easliy use it in Microsoft Office (Word, Powerpoint, etc). Some statistical software like **R** can directly export to WMF.

SPSS has WMF export mechanism. See this, Copying to Powerpoint should be the same thing:

- [Copying SPSS graphs to Word](http://support.appstate.edu/answers/copying-spss-graphs-word)